# adding Parameters using TRESTRequest

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

I have some issue to compile this portion of code :

```
RESTRequest.AddParameter('Id',edtId.Text,TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkGETorPOST);
```

it says :

> undeclared identifier  TRESTRequestParameterKind

I have dropped following components on the form :
`TRESTClient` , `TRESTRequest` , `TRestResponse`

Any idea What did I miss or why I have this error code ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to add `REST.Types` to your `uses` clause.

Comment: Hi Dalija, I have another issue now, when I add another parameters : RESTRequest.AddParameter('Id',edit1.Text,TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkGETorPOST); RESTRequest.AddParameter('Password',edit2.Text,TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkGETorPOST);  RESTRequest1.Execute; . with this I got an error : Protocol field is empty.  PS : Im still using delphi xe7 to realise android app. Any idea where is the problem ?

Comment: You probably need to add `RESTRequest.Method := TRESTRequestMethod.rmPOST;` or `RESTRequest.Method := TRESTRequestMethod.rmGET;`

Comment: Thanks for your  support Dalija, I m newbie on Delphi and also REST techniques, please bear with me if I ask silly question. Thanks again

Comment: It is fine to ask silly questions. But you can progress more quickly at start if you try to read documentation and try to look at some demo code that is provided with Delphi.